# Create a waveform of the full track with Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, html, audio, canvas, web-audio-api

**Realtime moving Waveform**

I'm currently playing with Web Audio API and made a spectrum using canvas.

```js
function animate(){
 var a=new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount),
     y=new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount),b,c,d;
 analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(y);
 analyser.getByteFrequencyData(a);
 b=c=a.length;
 d=w/c;
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
 while(b--){
  var bh=a[b]+1;
  ctx.fillStyle='hsla('+(b/c*240)+','+(y[b]/255*100|0)+'%,50%,1)';
  ctx.fillRect(1*b,h-bh,1,bh);
  ctx.fillRect(1*b,y[b],1,1);
 }
 animation=webkitRequestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

Mini question: is there a way to not write 2 times `new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount)`?

**DEMO**

add a MP3/MP4 file and wait. (tested in Chrome)

http://jsfiddle.net/pc76H/2/

But there are many problems. I can't find a proper documentation of the various audio filters.

Also, if you look at the spectrum you will notice that after 70% or the range there is no data. What does that mean? that maybe from 16k hz to 20k hz is no sound? I would apply a text to the canvas to show the various HZ. but where??

I found out that the returned data is a power of 32 in length with a max of 2048 
and the height is always 256.

**BUT the real question is ... I want to create a moving waveform like in traktor.**

I already did that some time ago with PHP it converts the file to low bitrate than extracts the data and coverts that to a image. i found the script somewhere...but I don't remember where...
note: needs *LAME*

```php
<?php
$a=$_GET["f"];
if(file_exists($a)){
    if(file_exists($a.".png")){
        header("Content-Type: image/png");
        echo file_get_contents($a.".png");
    }else{
        $b=3000;$c=300;define("d",3);
        ini_set("max_execution_time","30000");
        function n($g,$h){
            $g=hexdec(bin2hex($g));
            $h=hexdec(bin2hex($h));
            return($g+($h*256));
        };
        $k=substr(md5(time()),0,10);
        copy(realpath($a),"/var/www/".$k."_o.mp3");
        exec("lame /var/www/{$k}_o.mp3 -f -m m -b 16 --resample 8 /var/www/{$k}.mp3 && lame --decode /var/www/{$k}.mp3 /var/www/{$k}.wav");
        //system("lame {$k}_o.mp3 -f -m m -b 16 --resample 8 {$k}.mp3 && lame --decode {$k}.mp3 {$k}.wav");
        @unlink("/var/www/{$k}_o.mp3");
        @unlink("/var/www/{$k}.mp3");
        $l="/var/www/{$k}.wav";
        $m=fopen($l,"r");
        $n[]=fread($m,4);
        $n[]=bin2hex(fread($m,4));
        $n[]=fread($m,4);
        $n[]=fread($m,4);
        $n[]=bin2hex(fread($m,4));
        $n[]=bin2hex(fread($m,2));
        $n[]=bin2hex(fread($m,2));
        $n[]=bin2hex(fread($m,4));
        $n[]=bin2hex(fread($m,4));
        $n[]=bin2hex(fread($m,2));
        $n[]=bin2hex(fread($m,2));
        $n[]=fread($m,4);
        $n[]=bin2hex(fread($m,4));
        $o=hexdec(substr($n[10],0,2));
        $p=$o/8;
        $q=hexdec(substr($n[6],0,2));
        if($q==2){$r=40;}else{$r=80;};
        while(!feof($m)){
            $t=array();
            for($i=0;$i<$p;$i++){
                $t[$i]=fgetc($m);
            };
            switch($p){
                case 1:$s[]=n($t[0],$t[1]);break;
                case 2:if(ord($t[1])&128){$u=0;}else{$u=128;};$u=chr((ord($t[1])&127)+$u);$s[]= floor(n($t[0],$u)/256);break;
            };
            fread($m,$r);
        };
        fclose($m);
        unlink("/var/www/{$k}.wav");
        $x=imagecreatetruecolor(sizeof($s)/d,$c);
        imagealphablending($x,false);
        imagesavealpha($x,true);
        $y=imagecolorallocatealpha($x,255,255,255,127);
        imagefilledrectangle($x,0,0,sizeof($s)/d,$c,$y);
        for($d=0;$d<sizeof($s);$d+=d){
            $v=(int)($s[$d]/255*$c);
            imageline($x,$d/d,0+($c-$v),$d/d,$c-($c-$v),imagecolorallocate($x,255,0,255));
        };
        $z=imagecreatetruecolor($b,$c);
        imagealphablending($z,false);
        imagesavealpha($z,true);
        imagefilledrectangle($z,0,0,$b,$c,$y);
        imagecopyresampled($z,$x,0,0,0,0,$b,$c,sizeof($s)/d,$c);
        imagepng($z,realpath($a).".png");
        header("Content-Type: image/png");
        imagepng($z);
        imagedestroy($z);
    };
}else{
    echo $a;
};

?>
```

The script works... but you are limited to a max image size of 4k pixels.

so you have not a nice waveform if it should rappresent only some milliseconds.

**What do i need to store/create a realtime waveform like the traktors app or this php script? btw the traktor has also a colored waveform(the php script not).**

**EDIT**

I rewrote your script that it fits my idea... it's relatively fast.

As you can see inside the function createArray i push the various lines into an object with the key as x coordinate.

I'm simply taking the the highest number.

here is where we could play with the colors.

```js
var ajaxB,AC,B,LC,op,x,y,ARRAY={},W=1024,H=256;
var aMax=Math.max.apply.bind(Math.max, Math);
function error(a){
 console.log(a);
};
function createDrawing(){
 console.log('drawingArray');
 var C=document.createElement('canvas');
 C.width=W;
 C.height=H;
 document.body.appendChild(C);
 var context=C.getContext('2d');
 context.save();
 context.strokeStyle='#121';
 context.globalCompositeOperation='lighter';
 L2=W*1;
 while(L2--){
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(L2,0);
  context.lineTo(L2+1,ARRAY[L2]);
  context.stroke();
 }
 context.restore();
};
function createArray(a){
 console.log('creatingArray');
 B=a;
 LC=B.getChannelData(0);// Float32Array describing left channel
 L=LC.length;  
 op=W/L;
 for(var i=0;i<L;i++){
  x=W*i/L|0;
  y=LC[i]*H/2;
  if(ARRAY[x]){
   ARRAY[x].push(y)
  }else{
   !ARRAY[x-1]||(ARRAY[x-1]=aMax(ARRAY[x-1]));
   // the above line contains an array of values
   // which could be converted to a color 
   // or just simply create a gradient 
   // based on avg max min (frequency???) whatever
   ARRAY[x]=[y]
  }
 };
 createDrawing();
};
function decode(){
 console.log('decodingMusic');
 AC=new webkitAudioContext
 AC.decodeAudioData(this.response,createArray,error);
};
function loadMusic(url){
 console.log('loadingMusic');   
 ajaxB=new XMLHttpRequest;
 ajaxB.open('GET',url);
 ajaxB.responseType='arraybuffer';    
 ajaxB.onload=decode;
 ajaxB.send();
}
loadMusic('AudioOrVideo.mp4');
```

Comment: You want to generate a bitmap that will represent the waveform in its time representation ? Is that it ? And have the user download it ?

Comment: the php script does what you say already, i want to create a more advanved waveform that generates then later a high detailed rappresentation. i would also understand how traktor creates a colored waveform

Comment: so the user can change a waveform in the editor then save a graphic of this waveform ? Not the raw data itself ? not sure of the use-case here. For color, it's just about how you a lot of small vertical lines in a much lower resolution. The more samples that fits in a one-pixel screen line, the darker.

Comment: i want to create something like this http://newestra.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/traktor2-wave-formcolor.jpg one time then display it every time i play a song. but a image is to big if you want that detail.

Comment: Could you use webaudio ? it supports many, but not all Browsers (http://caniuse.com/audio-api)

Comment: it works on ios and chrome.i use only those devices...

Comment: if you check the demo.. of the first script on jsfiddle ... you will notice that i already use webaudio.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Ok, so what i would do is to load the sound with an XMLHttpRequest, then decode it using webaudio, then display it 'carefully' to have the colors you are searching for.

I just made a quick version, copy-pasting from various of my projects, it is quite working, as you might see with this picture :

[image]

The issue is that it is slow as hell. To have (more) decent speed, you'll have to do some computation to reduce the number of lines to draw on the canvas, because at 441000 Hz, you very quickly get too many lines to draw.

```
// AUDIO CONTEXT
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext ;

if (!AudioContext) alert('This site cannot be run in your Browser. Try a recent Chrome or Firefox. ');

var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var currentBuffer  = null;

// CANVAS
var canvasWidth = 512,  canvasHeight = 120 ;
var newCanvas   = createCanvas (canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
var context     = null;

window.onload = appendCanvas;
function appendCanvas() { document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);
                          context = newCanvas.getContext('2d'); }

// MUSIC LOADER + DECODE
function loadMusic(url) {   
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open( "GET", url, true );
    req.responseType = "arraybuffer";    
    req.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
          if (req.readyState == 4) {
             if(req.status == 200)
                  audioContext.decodeAudioData(req.response, 
                    function(buffer) {
                             currentBuffer = buffer;
                             displayBuffer(buffer);
                    }, onDecodeError);
             else
                  alert('error during the load.Wrong url or cross origin issue');
          }
    } ;
    req.send();
}

function onDecodeError() {  alert('error while decoding your file.');  }

// MUSIC DISPLAY
function displayBuffer(buff /* is an AudioBuffer */) {
   var leftChannel = buff.getChannelData(0); // Float32Array describing left channel     
   var lineOpacity = canvasWidth / leftChannel.length  ;      
   context.save();
   context.fillStyle = '#222' ;
   context.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight );
   context.strokeStyle = '#121';
   context.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
   context.translate(0,canvasHeight / 2);
   context.globalAlpha = 0.06 ; // lineOpacity ;
   for (var i=0; i<  leftChannel.length; i++) {
       // on which line do we get ?
       var x = Math.floor ( canvasWidth * i / leftChannel.length ) ;
       var y = leftChannel[i] * canvasHeight / 2 ;
       context.beginPath();
       context.moveTo( x  , 0 );
       context.lineTo( x+1, y );
       context.stroke();
   }
   context.restore();
   console.log('done');
}

function createCanvas ( w, h ) {
    var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    newCanvas.width  = w;     newCanvas.height = h;
    return newCanvas;
};


loadMusic('could_be_better.mp3');
```

Edit : The issue here is that we have too much data to draw. Take a 3 minutes mp3, you'll have 3*60*44100 = about 8.000.000 line to draw. On a display that has, say, 1024 px resolution, that makes 8.000 lines per pixel...
In the code above, the canvas is doing the 'resampling', by drawing lines with low-opacity and in 'ligther' composition mode (e.g. pixel's r,g,b will add-up).
To speed-up things, you have to re-sample by yourself, but to get some colors, it's not just a down-sampling, you'll have to handle a set (within a performance array most probably) of 'buckets', one for each horizontal pixel (so, say 1024), and in every bucket you compute the cumulated sound pressure, the variance, min, max and then, at display time, you decide how you will render that with colors.
For instance :
values between 0 positiveMin are very clear. (any sample is below that point).
values between positiveMin and positiveAverage - variance are darker,
values between positiveAverage - variance and positiveAverage + variance are darker,
and values between positiveAverage+variance and positiveMax lighter .
(same for negative values) 
That makes 5 colors for each bucket, and it's still quite some work, for you to code and for the browser to compute.
I don't know if the performance could get decent with this, but i fear the statistics accuracy and the color coding of the software you mention can't be reached on a browser (obviously not in real-time), and that you'll have to make some compromises.

Edit 2 :
I tried to get some colors out of stats but it quite failed. My guess, now, is that the guys at tracktor also change color depending on frequency.... quite some work here....

Anyway, just for the record, the code for an average / mean variation follows.
(variance was too low, i had to use mean variation).

[image]

```
// MUSIC DISPLAY
function displayBuffer2(buff /* is an AudioBuffer */) {
   var leftChannel = buff.getChannelData(0); // Float32Array describing left channel       
   // we 'resample' with cumul, count, variance
   // Offset 0 : PositiveCumul  1: PositiveCount  2: PositiveVariance
   //        3 : NegativeCumul  4: NegativeCount  5: NegativeVariance
   // that makes 6 data per bucket
   var resampled = new Float64Array(canvasWidth * 6 );
   var i=0, j=0, buckIndex = 0;
   var min=1e3, max=-1e3;
   var thisValue=0, res=0;
   var sampleCount = leftChannel.length;
   // first pass for mean
   for (i=0; i<sampleCount; i++) {
        // in which bucket do we fall ?
        buckIndex = 0 | ( canvasWidth * i / sampleCount );
        buckIndex *= 6;
        // positive or negative ?
        thisValue = leftChannel[i];
        if (thisValue>0) {
            resampled[buckIndex    ] += thisValue;
            resampled[buckIndex + 1] +=1;               
        } else if (thisValue<0) {
            resampled[buckIndex + 3] += thisValue;
            resampled[buckIndex + 4] +=1;                           
        }
        if (thisValue<min) min=thisValue;
        if (thisValue>max) max = thisValue;
   }
   // compute mean now
   for (i=0, j=0; i<canvasWidth; i++, j+=6) {
       if (resampled[j+1] != 0) {
             resampled[j] /= resampled[j+1]; ;
       }
       if (resampled[j+4]!= 0) {
             resampled[j+3] /= resampled[j+4];
       }
   }
   // second pass for mean variation  ( variance is too low)
   for (i=0; i<leftChannel.length; i++) {
        // in which bucket do we fall ?
        buckIndex = 0 | (canvasWidth * i / leftChannel.length );
        buckIndex *= 6;
        // positive or negative ?
        thisValue = leftChannel[i];
        if (thisValue>0) {
            resampled[buckIndex + 2] += Math.abs( resampled[buckIndex] - thisValue );               
        } else  if (thisValue<0) {
            resampled[buckIndex + 5] += Math.abs( resampled[buckIndex + 3] - thisValue );                           
        }
   }
   // compute mean variation/variance now
   for (i=0, j=0; i<canvasWidth; i++, j+=6) {
        if (resampled[j+1]) resampled[j+2] /= resampled[j+1];
        if (resampled[j+4]) resampled[j+5] /= resampled[j+4];   
   }
   context.save();
   context.fillStyle = '#000' ;
   context.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight );
   context.translate(0.5,canvasHeight / 2);   
  context.scale(1, 200);

   for (var i=0; i< canvasWidth; i++) {
        j=i*6;
       // draw from positiveAvg - variance to negativeAvg - variance 
       context.strokeStyle = '#F00';
       context.beginPath();
       context.moveTo( i  , (resampled[j] - resampled[j+2] ));
       context.lineTo( i  , (resampled[j +3] + resampled[j+5] ) );
       context.stroke();
       // draw from positiveAvg - variance to positiveAvg + variance 
       context.strokeStyle = '#FFF';
       context.beginPath();
       context.moveTo( i  , (resampled[j] - resampled[j+2] ));
       context.lineTo( i  , (resampled[j] + resampled[j+2] ) );
       context.stroke();
       // draw from negativeAvg + variance to negativeAvg - variance 
       // context.strokeStyle = '#FFF';
       context.beginPath();
       context.moveTo( i  , (resampled[j+3] + resampled[j+5] ));
       context.lineTo( i  , (resampled[j+3] - resampled[j+5] ) );
       context.stroke();
   }
   context.restore();
   console.log('done 231 iyi');
}
```

Comment: wow :), i didn't expected an answer like that ;) but let me first read the answer.

Comment: nice and it works great. You also know how the dj software traktor managed to create this colors based on frequency?

Comment: this is what i'm searching for... now i just need to store the data into an array.so i can later diplay a realtime moving waveform... hope it works.

Comment: i didn't understand correctly the color part but performance is not a problem as since i do this only one time per audio file.->upload new audio file,create waveform data,store data.then when you play the audio i uses the stored waveform data to display the waveform based on the audio currentTime.it would be nice if you could help me to complete this color question as i'm not that advanced as you with  audio data & canvas.btw a short js calc would be simpler for me to understand. and again even if it takes alot of time do draw/calculate all this is not a problem.

Comment: i just tested with a 20mb 320kb audio file got 17mil lines and worked perfectly.. current size is 8k px * 256 px

Comment: btw i could also convert the audio into an 8bit mono.... performance is no problem.

Comment: Fantastic answer!! if you plan to investigate in this color arrangement let me know!a solution would be to convert the audio to very low khz... like 8k then the decoding should be very fast.. first convert with something like lame and then decode and create waveform array.

Comment: i use hsla() to change the color. if you have a max,min values for the color. you could simply do hsla(360/max*val,100%,50%,0.1); or 240 red to blue

Comment: well, i just tried some statistics computations : 1) they are much faster than a plain draw of all figures 2) it's hard to have a nice visual, since 99.99% of the samples are near the curve... My guess is that the guys at traktor amplifies visually differences that are not that noticable... fun, but not that accurate :-)

Comment: y it would be better to create an array first (maybe save it also) with the needed values, then search a min-max and translate to 0-240 which in hsla is red to blue.and then later draw everything.

Comment: i edited another time !! Maybe you'll understand what i mean by buckets and statistics on sound.

Comment: i added also a faster version .... i try to understand yours now... in my version i have 2 problems as you notice: no gradients,and it's only a half wave(minor problem ;) )... but i totally don't understand how i could apply the colors for now... anyway learning your function now;

Comment: btw now the array loads fast.. almost fast enough to don't need to store the array somwhere. at the end the array will be :considering avg BPM of 120bpm so 2 every sec and as i want to view 128px btw every beat i need 120bpm*128px and array of 15360 values per minute so something like 70-100k numbers for a song....each of this values could contain max min avg ..whatever..

Comment: Based on your answer i made the what i needed. ecxept the colors.. if your also intrested like me, here is the code. http://jsfiddle.net/DAbh8/ to keep the animation as fluid as possible cache static values outside of the animation function.simply load a playable file in chrome.

Comment: Can someone explain, pls, what means resample values from 0 to 5? And what is the values of getChannelData? In simple words, pls =) if its hard to explain... ok... will read docs... And one more question: people record the same phrase, can i compare this records with this diagram? Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the top answer, I have controlled that by reducing number of lines want to draw and little canvas function call placement. see following code for your reference.

```js
// AUDIO CONTEXT
window.AudioContext = (window.AudioContext || 
window.webkitAudioContext || 
window.mozAudioContext || 
window.oAudioContext || 
window.msAudioContext);

if (!AudioContext) alert('This site cannot be run in your Browser. Try a recent Chrome or Firefox. ');

var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var currentBuffer  = null;

// CANVAS
var canvasWidth = window.innerWidth,  canvasHeight = 120 ;
var newCanvas   = createCanvas (canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
var context     = null;

window.onload = appendCanvas;
function appendCanvas() { document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);
                          context = newCanvas.getContext('2d'); }

// MUSIC LOADER + DECODE
function loadMusic(url) {   
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open( "GET", url, true );
    req.responseType = "arraybuffer";    
    req.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
          if (req.readyState == 4) {
             if(req.status == 200)
                  audioContext.decodeAudioData(req.response, 
                    function(buffer) {
                             currentBuffer = buffer;
                             displayBuffer(buffer);
                    }, onDecodeError);
             else
                  alert('error during the load.Wrong url or cross origin issue');
          }
    } ;
    req.send();
}

function onDecodeError() {  alert('error while decoding your file.');  }

// MUSIC DISPLAY
function displayBuffer(buff /* is an AudioBuffer */) {
  
  var drawLines = 500;
   var leftChannel = buff.getChannelData(0); // Float32Array describing left channel     
   var lineOpacity = canvasWidth / leftChannel.length  ;      
   context.save();
   context.fillStyle = '#080808' ;
   context.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight );
   context.strokeStyle = '#46a0ba';
   context.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
   context.translate(0,canvasHeight / 2);
   //context.globalAlpha = 0.6 ; // lineOpacity ;
   context.lineWidth=1;
   var totallength = leftChannel.length;
   var eachBlock = Math.floor(totallength / drawLines);
   var lineGap = (canvasWidth/drawLines);

  context.beginPath();
   for(var i=0;i<=drawLines;i++){
      var audioBuffKey = Math.floor(eachBlock * i);
       var x = i*lineGap;
       var y = leftChannel[audioBuffKey] * canvasHeight / 2;
       context.moveTo( x, y );
       context.lineTo( x, (y*-1) );
   }
   context.stroke();
   context.restore();
}

function createCanvas ( w, h ) {
    var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    newCanvas.width  = w;     newCanvas.height = h;
    return newCanvas;
};


loadMusic('could_be_better.mp3');
```

Answer (score 4):

this is a bit old, sorry to bump, but it's the only post about displaying a full waveform with the Web Audio Api and I'd like to share what method i used.

This method is not perfect but it only goes through the displayed audio and it only goes over it once. it also succeeds in displaying an actual waveform for short files or big zoom :
[image: waveform zoomed]

and a convincing loudness chart for bigger files dezoomed :
[image]

here is what it's like at middle zoom, kind of pleasant too:
[image]

notice that both zooms use the same algorythm.
I still struggle about scales (the zoomed waveform is bigger than the dezoomed one (though not so bigger than displayed on the images)

this algorythm i find is quite efficient (i can change zoom on 4mn music and it redraws flawlessly every 0.1s)

```js
function drawWaveform (audioBuffer, canvas, pos = 0.5, zoom = 1) {
  const canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d")
  const width = canvas.clientWidth
  const height = canvas.clientHeight
  canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
  canvasCtx.fillStyle  = "rgb(255, 0, 0)"

  // calculate displayed part of audio 
  // and slice audio buffer to only process that part
  const bufferLength = audioBuffer.length
  const zoomLength = bufferLength / zoom
  const start = Math.max(0, bufferLength * pos - zoomLength / 2)
  const end = Math.min(bufferLength, start + zoomLength)
  const rawAudioData = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).slice(start, end)

  // process chunks corresponding to 1 pixel width
  const chunkSize = Math.max(1, Math.floor(rawAudioData.length / width))
  const values = []
  for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    const start = x*chunkSize
    const end = start + chunkSize
    const chunk = rawAudioData.slice(start, end)
    // calculate the total positive and negative area
    let positive = 0
    let negative = 0
    chunk.forEach(val => 
      val > 0 && (positive += val) || val < 0 && (negative += val)
    )
    // make it mean (this part makes dezommed audio smaller, needs improvement)
    negative /= chunk.length
    positive /= chunk.length
    // calculate amplitude of the wave
    chunkAmp = -(negative - positive)
    // draw the bar corresponding to this pixel
    canvasCtx.fillRect(
      x,
      height / 2 - positive * height,
      1,
      Math.max(1, chunkAmp * height)
    )
  }
}
```

To use it :

```js
async function decodeAndDisplayAudio (audioData) { 
  const source = audioCtx.createBufferSource()

  source.buffer = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData)

  drawWaveform(source.buffer, canvas, 0.5, 1) 
  // change position (0//start -> 0.5//middle -> 1//end) 
  // and zoom (0.5//full -> 400//zoomed) as you wish
}

// audioData comes raw from the file (server send it in my case)
decodeAndDisplayAudio(audioData)
```