# Use AudioContext to display song's overall waveform

Tags: html, canvas, web-audio-api, audiocontext, janalyser

I am trying to display the waveform of a song pretty much like SoundCloud does it per individual track but I am having some difficulties.

So far this is what I am assuming to be the right start.

```
  $scope.audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  $scope.analyser = $scope.audioCtx.createAnalyser();

  $scope.myAudio = new Audio;
  $scope.myAudio.src = "http://localhost:9000/mp3/song.mp3";

  // Create a MediaElementAudioSourceNode
  // Feed the HTMLMediaElement into it
  $scope.source = $scope.audioCtx.createMediaElementSource( $scope.myAudio );

  $scope.source.connect( $scope.analyser );

  $scope.analyser.fftSize = 64;

  $scope.bufferLength = $scope.analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  $scope.dataArray = new Uint8Array( $scope.bufferLength );
  $scope.newDataArray = new Float32Array( $scope.analyser.fftSize );

  $scope.analyser.getByteTimeDomainData( $scope.dataArray );

  $scope.canvas = document.querySelector('.visualizer');
  $scope.canvasCtx = $scope.canvas.getContext("2d");

  function draw() {

    $scope.WIDTH = $scope.canvas.width;
    $scope.HEIGHT = $scope.canvas.height;

    $scope.drawVisual = requestAnimationFrame( draw );

    $scope.analyser.getByteTimeDomainData( $scope.dataArray );

    $scope.canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 200, 200)';
    $scope.canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, $scope.WIDTH, $scope.HEIGHT);

    $scope.canvasCtx.lineWidth = 2;
    $scope.canvasCtx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
  };

  draw();
```

Well this is obviously only partial, but the end result would be to display the overall track with the waveform of the track clearly represented from start to finish across the width of a canvas.

Much appreciate the help with this.

Respectfully,

Jules

Comment: Take a look at the [OfflineAudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a waveform of the full track with Web Audio API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073716/create-a-waveform-of-the-full-track-with-web-audio-api)

Comment: This question has been answered. Multiple times, I think. Take a look at the "related" questions on the right. One that seems pretty much the same is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073716/create-a-waveform-of-the-full-track-with-web-audio-api?rq=1