# How to get right amplitudes (without playing) of the audiotrack samples with web audio api

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I did some experiments with the samples volume data, provided to me by web audio api and it appeares that they are different from the data got from other programs like audasity for example. It shows the duration of audio longer at about 40 seconds if we take divide samples array length to sample rate (leftChannel.length/44100 in my case), and also where audacity shows loud samples in audio, my script shows quiet (almost silent sometimes). And I played pieces reported by my script as quiet in audacity and there is definitely loud sound.

So the question is: is my way to find ampitudes of audio samples correct? And what is wrong with my code?

I've read the thread about creating waveform for audiotrack [Create a waveform of the full track with Web Audio API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073716/create-a-waveform-of-the-full-track-with-web-audio-api?rq=1)
and there is good example of what I used, so here is my code:

```js
(function($) {

  window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  var context = new window.AudioContext(); // Create audio container
  var audioData;
  var checkPoint = 21; //this is point in seconds just for debugging, remove later!!
  function decode(audioData) {
    try{
        context.decodeAudioData(audioData,
        function(decoded){
            drawSound(decoded);
            playAudio(decoded);
        },
        function(){ // do nothing here
        });
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('decode exception',e.message);
    }
  }

  function drawSound(buffer) {
    var leftChannel = buffer.getChannelData(0);
    console.log('audio duration: ' + leftChannel.length/44100 + ' sec');
    for (var i = 0; i < leftChannel.length; i++) {
      var volume = leftChannel[i];
      //draw(volume, i);
      
      //this is just for debugging, remove later!!
      if (Math.abs(i - checkPoint * 44100) < 100) {
        console.log(leftChannel[i]);
      }
      
    }    
  }

  function playAudio(buffer) {
    console.log('start playing audio');
    var audioTrack = context.createBufferSource();
    audioTrack.connect(context.destination);
    audioTrack.buffer = buffer;
    audioTrack.start();
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append($('<input type="text" id="checkpoint" />'));
    $('#checkpoint').change(function() {
      checkPoint = $(this).val();
    });
    $('body').append($('<input type="file" id="audiofile" />'));
    $('input[type="file"]').change(function() {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        audioData = this.result;
        decode(audioData);
      };
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);      
    });
    
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Raymond Toy I've managed to solve this issue. It appeares that result returned by buffer.getChannelData(0) depends from computer audiocard's sample rate (which you can find from context.sampleRate). And if you want to find the length of track you should do it like this:

```
var samples = buffer.getChannelData(0);
var duration = samples/context.sampleRate;
```

And offset of sample from start in seconds is:

```
var sample = samples[i];
var offsetInSeconds = i/context.sampleRate
```

My mistake was that I used mp3 audiotrack's sample rate in formulas and this caused errors on computer with different audiocard sample rate.

As Raymond Toy noticed, if you need only duration of audio you can get it even simpler like this:

```
var duration = buffer.duration;
```

Comment: Why not just use buffer.duration? This is the duration of buffer in sec.

Comment: Yes, you are right, for duration it works fine, but I needed actually samples for user to visualize and cut certain part of audio (short piece like  for rington on the phone)

Answer (score 1):

If you think this is a bug in Chrome, please file a bug at crbug.com/new. And provide one audiotrack that produces different results and details about the different machines.

Note also that in chrome, ffmpeg is used to decode the files.  The decoded file could differ in length from audacity.

Comment: As I already said this is not only Chrome bug, but at least Chrome and Firefox bug, but actually I suppose it lies somewhere deeper. It shows up on all mp3 tracks I tried on one of two my computers and breaks totally working of all further application algorithms, while on other computer all works as expected, though both computers have the same operational system and equal versions of browsers.

Comment: Providing a small self-contained snippet (jsbin or jsfiddle) including the mp3 file that causes a problem would help a lot in tracking this down.  Also include the versions of Chrome you used and the kind of computer where it does and does not work.

Comment: I added jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rdLkkuaq/ with snippet and loaded  to filedropper mp3 which I used for testing (though this is not the only one which I used, you can try with other mp3 too), here is the url http://www.filedropper.com/revolutionrussellbrandaudiobookextractbyrussellbrandpdvizhbhrnhp128 .

Comment: version of Chrome on both computers is 42.0.2311.152

Comment: One computer (desktop) has processor Intel(R) core(TM) i5 cpu, the other one (minidesk) has processor Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 1037U, both have the same operational system Windows 7. The buggy behavior happens on the second computer.

Comment: I forgot to add that Windows 7 is 64bit

Comment: Print out the value of context.sampleRate too for each computer.  The sample rates on the different machines could be different.  If that does not match the sample rate of the mp3 file, webaudio will resample the mp3 file to the context sample rate which can cause some differences in the length of the buffer.

Comment: Raymond, I updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rdLkkuaq/1/ and you were right about different sample rates, on computer with buggy behavior context.sampleRate=48000 and on other computer context.sampleRate=44100 (equals to mp3 sample rate). Now the question is how to make webaudio give me correct volume of samples on all computers, for now where it shows quiet pieces I start to play from that point and there is loud sound (on the second comp visually low volume samples start playing really quiet as expected)

Comment: I'm really confused by what you mean by "correct volume of samples on all computers".  Again, a jsfiddle that illustrates this will help a lot in figuring this out.  (But please use a short file instead of a 5 min clip.)

Comment: Hurray, Raymond Thanks for your great help! I used mp3 audiotrack's sample rate while transforming index of sample to offset in seconds from beginning like this: var offsetInSeconds = sampleIndex/audiotrack.sampleRate, now I changed this transformation to var offsetInSeconds = sampleIndex/context.sampleRate and everything works correct on both computers.

Answer (score 0):

I've made more thorough measurements and more testing and found that there is no  error in my script,  BUT!! web audio api gives the results equal to audasity both for the length of audiotrack and for the amplitudes on one of my computers (both in Chrome and Firefox) and wrong results on another computer (again browser independently), so I conclude that web audio api uses some low level processor dependent features because I have the same OS (windows 7) on both my computers, the only difference is hardware. 
The code, provided in my post is working as expected.

Comment: Did you try to use buffer.duration instead of dividing channel length on frequency?

Comment: Ken, thanks for your comment, you are right about buffer.duration, this variable is consistent, equal on both my computers and on one computer it's value equals to buffer.getChannelData(0) and on other they are different (in Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: Is the source file an MP3? I am just guessing here, but perhaps it's possible that the resulting buffer is a result of block-based decoding/decompression while duration is calculated/fetched differently (ie. header if possible, mp3s only have frame headers IIRC so you need to scan the file to find duration, but I could remember this part wrong).

Comment: Yes, I tested on different mp3 files (I uploaded one to filedropper and made jsfiddle, look in my comment for Raymond Toy). So the question now how to get good samples (the function buffer.getChannelData(0) evidently behaves inconsistently on different computers in my case).