# Web Audio API - Create AudioBufferSourceNode from another node?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, canvas, web-audio-api

Is it possible to create an AudioBufferSourceNode from another node?

The reason I ask is that I'm trying to create a waveform visualization, not just from a buffer source, but of an entire finished song that I "program"  with the web audio API. I can time and program the song perfectly and it sounds just the way I want in the end. I can also create individual visualizations from the source WAV files that I use to create the song.

I used the code from this post to create the visualizations and show them in multiple canvases:

[Create a waveform of the full track with Web Audio API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073716/create-a-waveform-of-the-full-track-with-web-audio-api)

So here's the code snippet that creates the visualizations:

```
var canvas1 = document.querySelector('.visualizer1');
var canvasCtx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
createvis(mybuffer, canvasCtx1);

function createvis(buff, Ctx) {

        var leftChannel = buff.getChannelData(0); // Float32Array describing left channel     
        var lineOpacity = 640 / leftChannel.length;
        Ctx.save();
        Ctx.fillStyle = '#222';
        Ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 640, 100);
        Ctx.strokeStyle = '#121';
        Ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
        Ctx.translate(0, 100 / 2);
        Ctx.globalAlpha = 0.06; // lineOpacity ;

        for (var i = 0; i < leftChannel.length; i++) {
            // on which line do we get ?
            var x = Math.floor(640 * i / leftChannel.length);
            var y = leftChannel[i] * 100 / 2;
            Ctx.beginPath();
            Ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
            Ctx.lineTo(x + 1, y);
            Ctx.stroke();
        }
        Ctx.restore();
    }
```

The results ended up being pretty cool. I end up with an image for each source buffer that looks something like this:

http://www.bklorraine.com/waveform.png

However, as I load my various source buffers into createBufferSource nodes, I chain them and add effects and it would be nice for the waveforms I generate here to reflect these effects. It would also be nice if the final context.destination that contains the output of everything (ie the finished song) could have a visualization as well.

I would also like to eventually change my "program" so that it doesn't just assemble a song from source wav files, but also combines them with nodes that generate a signal from scratch and, obviously, these particular sounds wouldn't have any sort of source buffer to create a visualization from.

Does anyone know if this is possible using the javascript web audio api?

Comment: So you want to create a visualization of something you didn't have done yet ? I mean, all these filters etc. are done in real-time right? So beside this XY issue, I see two options for you : **1.** do the visualizations in real-time too, thanks to the [`scriptProcessorNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createScriptProcessor), **2** record your output once, then convert this recorded audio to an AudioBufferSourceNode and do like you're doing, or even, just store the output image & audio somewhere, since it will loose any advantages of real-time.

Comment: Somethkng like Option #2 was what I was thinking. I'm perfectly willing to do a sort of "first pass" to get visualizations and THEN run it a second time to actually listen to the song

Comment: Thanks for the edit, quite hard to decipher the first comment ;-) Then you still have at least two options. You could use the scriptProcessorNode, save all the values you need, and create the viz at the end, or you can use a MediaRecorder, record your song, then pass the saved Blob to a FileReader in order to get its arrayBuffer version, and finally use decodeAudioData like you are doing. But I would recommend you to learn how to use the scriptProcessorNode, it offers way more scalability than what you are doing now.